# concatenate two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have year and month column in my pandas data frame and i want to concatenate them by as a string so that i can convert them into datetime.

df.info() gives

```
Data columns (total 3 columns):
years         372 non-null object
months        372 non-null object
windSpeedM    371 non-null float64
```

and the data looks like

```
years  month windSpeedM
1985    1   0.4
```

i am trying this

```
ff2['date'] = ff2['years']+'-'+ff2['months']+'-'+'01'
```

i am getting an error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')
```

Comment: ff2['date'] = ff2['years'].map(str)+'-'+ff2['months'].map(str)+'-'+'01'

Comment: It works perfectly fine thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ff2['date'] = ff2['years'].map(str)+'-'+ff2['months'].map(str)+'-'+'01'
```